# How do I override ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer when I yield a hash provided in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

My `profile.html.erb` provides a hash upstream to the layout.html.erb to be included in the metadata

```
  <% provide(:twitter, { %>
  <% card: 'summary', %>
  <% site: '@twitter', %>
  <% title: 'Lorem ipsum', %>
  <% description: 'Non sequitar', %>
  <% image: gravatar_for(@user, { size: 150 } )%>
  <% }) %>
```

The `layout.html.erb` then is supposed to iterate over this and create the meta tags:

```
  <% yield(:twitter).each do |key, value|%>
  <meta name="twitter:#{key}" content="#{value}" />
  <% end %>
```

However, it gives me the error `undefined method 'each' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x007f8d616e5870>`, and after inspecting `yield(:twitter)` with `byebug` I see that I yield an instance of `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`:

```
(byebug) hash = yield(:twitter)
"{:card=&gt;&quot;summary&quot;, :site=&gt;&quot;@twitter&quot;, :title=&gt;&quot;Lorem ipsum&quot;, :description=&gt;&quot;Non sequitar&quot;, :image=&gt;&quot;https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/a937016807c66d89d0a62d7a1b235533?s=150&quot;}"
(byebug) hash.class
ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer
```

I could eval the string into a hash, but `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` encodes it html safe, and there's no method to get the original back out. Is there a smarter way to do this, or do I have to hack around it with a helper converting the string back into a hash, and then `eval()`ing it into a has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since provide expects either a string or a block then it might be better to create the meta tags in a helper and pass it as string argument.

```
module TwitterHelper
  def twitter_meta_tags(hash)
     hash.each_with_object([]) do |(key, value), array|
        a.push( tag(:meta, { name: "twitter:#{k}", content: v }, false, false ) )
     end.join("\n").html_safe
     # not sure if that last html_safe is really needed.
  end
end
```

Downstream view:

```
<%
provide(:twitter, twitter_meta_tags({
  foo: "bar"
}));
%>
```

Layout:

```
<%= yield(:twitter) %>
```

### Using a partial

Another option is to use a partial and pass a block instead of a string to `provide`:

```
<% # app/views/twitter/_meta_tags.html.erb %>
<% hash.each do |key, value|%>
  <meta name="twitter:#{key}" content="#{value}" />
<% end %>
```

Downstream view:

```
<% provide(:twitter) do %>
  <%= render partial: "twitter/meta_tags", hash: {
    card: 'summary', 
    site: '@twitter',
    title: 'Lorem ipsum',
    description: 'Non sequitar',
    image: gravatar_for(@user, { size: 150 } )
  } %>
<% end %>
```

Layout:

```
<%= yield(:twitter) %>
```

Comment: The partial method is without a doubt the best method I've seen so far!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the following:

```
  <% twitter_tags = String.new yield(:twitter)%>
  <% twitter_tags = eval ( CGI.unescapeHTML( twitter_tags ) ) %>

  <% twitter_tags.each do |key, value|%>
    <%= tag(:meta, name: "twitter:#{key}", content: (value) )%>
  <% end %>
```

IMHO this is an extremely ugly way of hacking around the problem. I'll write a helper to take away most of this from the view, however, if you have a more elegant solution, please share it and I'll accept your answer instead of mine.

By the default, all the provided values are instances of `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`, this converts it into a string, and evaluates it into a hash again.